# Trying to create a basic calculator

Tags: c++

However when Input "12 + 3" it outputs "154" or if I input "12+1" it outputs "1312". Multiplication also doesn't seem to work consistently. Division seems ok for the most part

```
    #include <iostream>
    
    
    int main()
    {
        int firstNum, secondNum, res;
        std::string op; 
    std::cout << "Enter desired operation ";
    std::cin >> firstNum >> op >> secondNum;
    if (op=="+")
    {
        res = firstNum + secondNum;
        std::cout << res;
    }
    else if(op==" - ")
    {
        res = firstNum - secondNum;
        std::cout << res;
    }
    else if(op==" x ")
    {
        res = firstNum * secondNum;
        std::cout << res;
    }
    else if(op==" / ");
    {
        res = firstNum / secondNum;
        std::cout << res;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `4` in `154` and `12` in `1312` are the result of division.

You have two errors:

- You have extra spaces in `" - "`, `" * "`, and `" / "`, preventing them from matching to `op`.
- You have an extra semicolon after `else if(op==" / ")`, having it do the division unconditionally.

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>


int main()
{
    int firstNum, secondNum, res;
    std::string op; 
    std::cout << "Enter desired operation ";
    std::cin >> firstNum >> op >> secondNum;
    if (op=="+")
    {
        res = firstNum + secondNum;
        std::cout << res;
    }
    else if(op=="-")
    {
        res = firstNum - secondNum;
        std::cout << res;
    }
    else if(op=="x")
    {
        res = firstNum * secondNum;
        std::cout << res;
    }
    else if(op=="/")
    {
        res = firstNum / secondNum;
        std::cout << res;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `op` should be a `char`, not a `std::string`. If the input is like `12+1` with no spaces, then `op` will receive `+1` instead of just `+`, leaving `secondNum` indeterminate.